# Spring boot bean null exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataProcessorApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
   SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DataProcessorApplication.class);
   app.run();
}
```

PostProcessor class

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class BeanRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanRegistryPostProcessor.class);

  @Autowired
  private DataConfigurationService dataConfigurationService;

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory)
      throws BeansException {
    // we don't want to touch existing beans
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry){
    dataConfigurationService.something(); // service bean is null here
  }
}
```

My Service class

```
@Service
public class DataConfigurationService implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataConfigurationService.class);

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent e) {
    LOG.debug("Loading active DataConfiguration instance...");
  }
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at dataprocessor.configmodels.processor.BeanRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanRegistryPostProcessor.java:40)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:685)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:736)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at dataprocessor.DataProcessorApplication.main(DataProcessorApplication.java:47)

2017-01-07 12:42:47.802  WARN 8880 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7a138fc5: startup date [Sat Jan 07 12:42:46 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1004)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:793)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
    at dataprocessor.DataProcessorApplication.main(DataProcessorApplication.java:47)

2017-01-07 12:42:47.803 ERROR 8880 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7a138fc5: startup date [Sat Jan 07 12:42:46 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:958)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:793)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
    at dataprocessor.DataProcessorApplication.main(DataProcessorApplication.java:47)
```

POM

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring initializes context in next sequence:

First, based on application configuration and automatically detected classes(`@Component`, `@Service` etc) bean definitions will be created and registered in `BeanDefinitionRegistry`.

After that Spring will auto-detect beans which implement [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) in their bean definitions and apply them before any other beans get created. Since your `BeanRegistryPostProcessor` is implementation of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` it will be applied on this step.

After that Spring will auto-detect all beans which implement [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) interface and will apply them to any beans subsequently created. One of this beans is `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which processes `@Autoware` annotation. That means your service will be injected on this step.

As you see you're trying to use `DataConfigurationService` bean before it will be injected into `BeanRegistryPostProcessor`. For solve this problem you can implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface in `BeanRegistryPostProcessor` and then get instance of service directly from application context:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class BeanRegistryPostProcessor 
    implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    ...

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry){
      DataConfigurationService service = applicationContext.getBean(DataConfigurationService.class);
      service.something();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
      this.applicationContext = applicationContext;            
    }
}
```

More details about so called Container Extension Points you can find in Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension).

Comment: So if i replace Component to Confguration for Service will it solve the issue ?

Comment: @SaurabhKumar No. Because anyway `@Autowired` annotation will be processed AFTER `BeanRegistryPostProcessor` was applied. I little bit updated the answer.